# jquery manipulate html

Tags: javascript, jquery

my dynamic generated html look like below

```
<ul class="missingList">
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer2</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer2</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer2</li>
</ul>
```

i want to use jquery to check for all duplication filter the result so that the output become

```
<ul class="missingList">
<li>Please select at least one answer</li>
<li>Please select at least one answer2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are the equal nodes always consecutive?

Comment: If you are generating the list server-side, why don't you eliminate the duplicates server-side, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.missingList li').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == $(this).next().text()) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

But if you are generating the list with PHP, it would be better to filter the result on its site, like bogdanvursu suggested.

Edit:

I think [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) would be better for this. Here is an example

```
$array = array(1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6);
$array = array_unique($array);
```

The result would look like this (1, 4, 5, 6)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like a dictionary to keep track of the li`s html...

```
var obj ={};
$('.missingList').find('<li>').each(function)
{
    $this = $(this);
    if(obj[this.html()]
        $this.parent().removeChild(this);
    else
        obj[$this.html()] = {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.missingList").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();

  if ($(this).prevAll().filter(function() { return $(this).text() == text; }).length > 0)
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way, which doesn't consider the order in which the items are traversed.

```
$('.missingList li').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).next().length) return;
    var currText = $(this).text();
    $(this).nextAll().filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() == currText;
    }).remove();
});
```

[Here's a worked out example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cg7R/2/)

I do agree that this should be handled on the server before going into JavaScript though.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there the following JQuery/javascript function should do it. As it is a bit late at night I didnt get to test it or tidy it.

```
function RemoveDups() {

   var $res = $("ul.missingList li");
   $res.remove();
    var i;

    $res.sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($(a).text() < $(b).text()) return -1;
    if ($(a).text() == $(b).text()) return 0;
    return 1;
 });
lis=new Array();
lis.push($res[0]);
for (i = 1; i < $res.length; i++)
if($($res[i-1]).text()!=$($res[i]).text()) lis.push($res[i]);
 $("ul.missingList").after(lis);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the LIs? In PHP you can use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to filter the array.